# Hook tex macro without altering tokens stream

Tags: tex-core, luatex, hooks

Is is possible to hook a macro with function which writes some info 
to file or log without altering stream which creates dvi file. For example if i have macro definition

```
\def\foo{\mathop{A}}
```

and i hook it with

```
\def\foo{{\ifmmode\typeout{math}\else\typeout{text}\fi}\mathop{A}}
```

it gives me different output for expressions like.

```
$\max \foo$
```

Because it alters stream `mathop, mathop --> mathop, something, mathop`.
I don't know luatex, but solutions with help of lua code are also appreciated.

Comment: In general, no.  In your particular case, `\def\foo{\mathop{A\ifmmode\typeout{math}\else\typeout{text}\fi}}` should do the trick (and here, `\ifmmode` had better be true, as `\mathop` should only be used in math mode).

Comment: sorry, my question should be more general. I need to hook any macro without knowing anything about it a priori without altering original stream.

Comment: Okay, I should say "with pdfTeX and with XeTeX, I think that the precise thing you are hoping for is impossible in general, and with LuaTeX I suspect that the appropriate hooks are not available".  One approach that is not too intrusive for typesetting is to do what you did, but without surrounding braces around the extra code, or with braces replaced by `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spacing difference in

```
\def\foo{{\ifmmode\typeout{math}\else\typeout{text}\fi}\mathop{A}}
```

does not come from the `\typeout` it comes from the `{}` You would see the same with

```
\def\foo{{}\mathop{A}}
```

as in math mode `{}` makes a mathord atom so affects the space of surrounding symbols. Compare `$+2` to `${}+2`.

As `\typeout` is an `\immediate\write` and does not use a `{}` group internally (it uses `\begingroup \endgroup` for exactly this reason) it does not introduce any atoms into a math list or nodes into a horizontal or vertical list.

So as Bruno noted in comments

```
 \def\foo{\ifmmode\typeout{math}\else\typeout{text}\fi\mathop{A}}
```

However as the start of an array cell that will take the wrong (math) choice as it will expand before the math delimiters have been inserted by the array preamble code. You could put `\relax` in front or move the test to the end, or (perhaps best) use `\protected\def`

```
 \def\foo{\relax\ifmmode\typeout{math}\else\typeout{text}\fi\mathop{A}}

 \def\foo{\mathop{A}\ifmmode\typeout{math}\else\typeout{text}\fi}

 \protected\def\foo{\ifmmode\typeout{math}\else\typeout{text}\fi\mathop{A}}
```

The `\protected` version is "safe" in `\edef` `\section{}` and other moving arguments, although of course it's behaviour is different from the unmodified version, it would mean for example `\foo` gets written to the table of contents and expanded when the toc is input, rather than `\mathop{A}` being written to the table of contents.

TeX is a macro processing language where the entire program is available as data. One of the reasons why we are so reluctant to change LaTeX definitions in any way (and so have packages like `fixltx2e` that allow you to explicitly opt in to changes is that experience shows that if you modify a definition in *any* way, somewhere someone's document will break. Packages can and do patch commands in arbitrary ways, inserting arbitrary tokens in the *expansion* of arbitrary commands, and so if you change the expansion things go wrong.

Consider a command `\AtoB` that redefines a command to use `B` instead of `A`. It works with the original definition but fails with any redefinition.  If you look through this site you will see this kind of patch *all the time* it is not (just) a made up example.

```
\def\AtoB#1{\expandafter\xAtoB#1\xAtoB#1}
\def\xAtoB#1#2\xAtoB#3{\def#3{#1{B}}}

\def\foo{\mathop{A}}
\AtoB\foo
\show\foo


\protected\def\foo{\ifmmode\typeout{math}\else\typeout{text}\fi\mathop{A}}
\AtoB\foo
\show\foo


\stop
```

Produces

```
> \foo=macro:
->\mathop {B}.
l.9 \show\foo
```

Good.

```
? 
> \foo=macro:
->\ifmmode {B}.
l.14 \show\foo

?
```

Oops:-)